# Get exact match from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

```
res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match": {'author':'kimchy'}}})
```

Following search returns all authors matching 'kimchy', even if it is 'kimchy 1', 'kimchy 2'. I want only exact match 'kimchy'. Is there any option to get exact match in elastic search.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `filter` not `match` I think

```
GET /my_store/products/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "test-index" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : {
                    "author" : "kimchy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

see also [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)

Comment: Getting below error: elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'no [query] registered for [test-index]')

Comment: Try removing the query portion, and please add your command after editing it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your field has been analyzed when indexed - There is no way for exact-matching. If you want to achieve the exact match and tokens should be searchable the mapping should be "not_analyzed" and the data needs to be re-indexed.